# Как задать input файл для oozie workflow?

Tags: python, input, csv, hadoop, workflow

Код на python. Действия следующие: считываем таблицу и выводим её на экран

```
import csv
import sys

input = sys.stdin

for row in csv.reader(input):
    print row
```

Сама таблица находится на hdfs, путь: */user/username/table.csv*.
Пробовал настроить следующее:

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.input.dir</name>
    <value>/user/username/table.csv</value>
</property>
```

но в логе бесконечно выдаёт:

```
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
Heart beat
```

**Вопрос:** как задать `table.csv` для `input` в oozie workflow?

Answer (score 1):

Свойство `mapred.input.dir` подразумевает, что в его значении будет указана директория, а не отдельный файл. Соответственно укажите значение `/user/username` вместо `/user/username/table.csv` и в указанной папке все файлы будут взяты в роли входных данных. В случае, если вы хотите прочитать только один файл - скопируйте его в отдельную директорию и укажите путь до неё.